# How to deep search into hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a key that contain hash and array and I want to search this value into result that get from web app.

> for example: search_key = {search: [{user: [:first_name, {address: [:state,
>   :city, :zip]}]}, :count], search2: [:location]}

Search_key can contain any key and value. Here key is not static it creating dynamic so it may be any.

```
db_data = {
       search{ 
          user: {
            first_name: "Test user",
            address: {
              street: "main street",
              state: nil,
              city: "Delhi",
              zip: "12345"
            },
          },
          count: 55
          test: 123
        },
        search2:{
          location: "main_data"
          mobile_no: '9998887776'
        }
       }
```

I need to fetch check data is present or not with below key basis:

> search_key = {search: [{user: [:first_name, {address: [:state, :city,
>   :zip]}]}, :count], search2: [:location]}

here search_key means:

```
db_data[:search]
db_data[:search][:user]
db_data[:search][:user][:first_name]
db_data[:search][:user][:address]
db_data[:search][:user][:address][:state]
db_data[:search][:user][:address][:city]
db_data[:search][:user][:address][:zip]
db_data[:search][:count]
db_data[:search2]
db_data[:search2][:location]
```

> **NOTE:: search_key is not static. search_key's key will be change always and search_key may be any type, like hash of array, array of
>   hash. array of array, hash of hash of hash

I need to check all the key is present or not if one of the key is nil then it should return false

in db_data
db_data[:search][:user][:address][:state] is nil then the function should return false.

if the value exist in db_data[:search][:user][:address][:state] then the function should return true.

[EDIT]:

I have tried with this function

```
def data_present?(data, keys)
  keys.each do |k,v|
    return false if data[k].nil?
    if v.is_a?  Array
      v.each do |a|
        if a.is_a? Hash
          data_present?(data[k], a) if data[k].is_a?Hash
          return data[k].each{|r| return data_present?(r, v) } if data[k].is_a?Array
        else
          return false if data[k][a].nil?
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

called by

> data_present?(db_data, search_key)

The recursive function call is not working properly. Please let me know where I am doing wrong

Comment: The title of the post says "deep search" a `Hash` which is not an uncommon request and usually fairly simple to implement through recursion. When reading the actual post I am completely lost as to how you are defining this task because you are saying that search_key can be multiple `Enumerable` type objects which makes this far more complex. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: That is not a valid hash.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I tried but not working with recursion. do you have any idea?

Comment: @vijaychouhan If you haven't tried recursion, you're missing a powerful tool when solving problems. This is a perfect opportunity to practice. I've also found that using `case` makes breaking out handlers for Array, Hash, etc. a whole lot easier.

Comment: In `db_data` you need to change "search" to a symbol and add a couple of commas. Please always test before posting.

Comment: @vijaychouhan I have added an answer for you since I was still unclear I tried to take care of everything you discussed. Might not all be needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
class Hash
  def flatten_to_key_hierarchy(exclude_nils=false)
    deep_key_retrieval(exclude_nils).each_with_object({}) do |h,obj|
      obj.merge!(h)
    end
  end
  def deep_key_retrieval(exclude_nils=false)
    map do |k,v|
      if v.is_a?(Hash) 
        Hash[k,v.deep_key_retrieval]
      else
        k unless v.nil? && exclude_nils
      end
    end.compact
  end
end
```

This will produce

```
db_data = {
       :search=>{
         :user=>{
           :first_name=>"Test user", 
           :address=>{
             :street=>"main street", 
             :state=>nil, 
             :city=>"Delhi", 
             :zip=>"12345"}
           }, 
           :count=>55, 
           :test=>123
        }, 
        :search2=>{
          :location=>"main_data", 
          :mobile_no=>"9998887776"
        }
      }
db_data.flatten_to_key_hierarchy
#=>{:search=>[{:user=>[:first_name, {:address=>[:street, :state, :city, :zip]}]},
    :count, :test], :search2=>[:location, :mobile_no]}
```

Like I said I am not sure I completely understand what you are looking for but this seems to match your intended result.

Saw you updated your question. Try adding this to the above

```
def data_present?(input={},valid_object={},exclude_nils=false)
   input = input.flatten_to_key_hierarchy(exclude_nils)
   validate_against_keys(input,valid_object)
end
private
  def validate_against_keys(input={},valid_object={})
    valid_object.each do |k,v|
      return false unless input.has_key?(k) && input[k].class == v.class
      if v.is_a?(Hash)
        validate_against_keys(input[k],v)
      elsif v.is_a?(Array)
        return false unless v - input[k] == []
      end
    end
    true
  end
```

`#data_present?` will take your raw `db_data` as input and the already determined structure as valid_object. It will ignore additional keys in db_data only looking for the ones specified in test_data

```
test_data =  db_data.flatten_to_key_hierarchy
data_present?(db_data,test_data,true)
#=> true
test_data[:search].delete(:test)
data_present?(db_data,test_data,true)
#=> true
test_data[:search] << :something_else
data_present?(db_data,test_data,true)
#=> false
```

Comment: You don't need `obj` or `self.`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes thank you. I have removed them for you although I usually leave them in for clarification purposes. Especially `obj` as the return for `each_with_object` as this seems to get missed a lot.

Comment: I am a hobbiest, not a worker bee, so take my opinion with a grain of a salt, but I have a different view: whenever you add anything unnecessary you are implying that it needs to be there, which does not benefit the reader. On the other hand, if you don't do that (`.̶s̶e̶l̶f̶`, for example), and the reader is puzzled by the omission, he/she will soon figure it out and learn something they need to know.